# large group of variable IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a working query that contains a large number of variable IDs.  Rather than copying and pasting in each ID whenever I need to run a new query, I was wondering if there was a way to create a stored procedure out of the query below and pass in a group of IDs?

Here is the query.  The IDs change all the time, so I'm trying to figure out a way of doing this easier but I'm not having much luck.

I thought about using a cursor in a stored procedure and just passing each ID, but that seems cumbersome and inefficient.

```
   SELECT gm.geoId, T.number As surveyID, 0 as SpeciesCount
   FROM ( 
    VALUES (1994328036),(1994328037),(1994328038),(1994328039),(1994328040),(1994328041),(1994328042),(1994328043),
           (1994328044),(1994328045),(1994328046),(1994328047),(1994328048),(1994328049),(1994328050),(1994328051),
           (1994328052),(1994328053),(1994328054),(1994328055)
    ) AS T(number)
   CROSS JOIN dbo.groupBiology gm
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is the difference between putting the ids in a stored procedure and putting them in a `vALUES` statement?  Why not just use a temporary table or table variable?

Comment: And what is the purpose of the crossjoin here?

Comment: If the IDs change you are going to need to enter them somewhere.

Comment: @Rikalous From inspection a row for each gm.geoId and T.number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `table-valued function` (TVF) like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tvf_GetIDs ()
RETURNS 
@output TABLE ( data int )
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @output (data) VALUES
   (1994328036),(1994328037),(1994328038),(1994328039),
   (1994328040),(1994328041),(1994328042),(1994328043),
   (1994328044),(1994328045),(1994328046),(1994328047),
   (1994328048),(1994328049),(1994328050),(1994328051),
   (1994328052),(1994328053),(1994328054),(1994328055)

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

then use this function wherever the IDs are required, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers AS c
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tvf_GetIDs()) t ON c.CustID = t.data
```

You only need to update the TVF whenever the IDs change.

Comment: Why not use a view instead? It would be a lot simpler.